# sum row content with matching columns

Tags: php, mysql

**Yes yes, I know. The title is stupid and hard to understand.**

---

Question:

There's a `DB1` and a `DB2`.

---

`DB1` has `column`s called `id` and `price`. `id` is a unique number for each item like `301` and so on. There's only one of each `id` in this `DB`.

---

`DB2` contains a column named `id` and one named `price`. This DB has the duty of collecting data about each `id` ( item ) via a `php` script.

This means multiple rows with the same unique `id`.

a picture to demonstrate:

[image: Multiple Rows]

---

What i'm trying to do:

**a script that querys an `id`** ( matches the id with another table ) and `sum`s up all the `price` columns with the same `id`.

I understand `innerjoin`

```
SELECT db1.id, db2.price
FROM db1
INNER JOIN db2
ON db1.id=db2.id;
```

but I want to `sum` all `db2.price` rows before showing. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you want is this:**

(I guess you want to show db1.price too (or other fields from db1, otherwise there is no meaning have this join)

```
SELECT db1.id, db1.price, db2s.price -- rest of db1 fields here
FROM db1
INNER JOIN (select id, sum(price) price from db2 group by id) as db2s
ON db1.id=db2s.id;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e597/1)

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much for helping me out !

Comment: One last question, how can I add a `WHERE` clause?


http://paste.ofcode.org/eWBQNtjfU8veTpbfzKLQYD


This didn't work. Also, I have no idea how to echo the sum in php. 

`$row["community1s"]` wasn't it.

Comment: remove the semicolon before the `where` and for the echo you can alias all columns like `select ..community1s.price as com_price..` and then do `$row["com_price"]`

Comment: so I can't `select` again in the same string, can I?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a join for that. It should be enough to just do:

```
SELECT id, sum(price) as price_sum FROM db2 GROUP BY id
```

This should give you 2 columns:

- id of the price
- sum of all prices for given price ID